# Put logic within a stateless child component or send prop values back to stateful parent and perform logic there?

Tags: reactjs

```
const TrackerRow = (props) => {
  const renderCampaignItems = props.group.map(
    campaign => <CampaignRow key={campaign.tracker + '|' + campaign.token} name={campaign.tracker} token={campaign.token} />)

  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{renderCampaignItems}</td>
      <td><a onClick={props.onDeleteTracker}>Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
  )
}
```

I have a series of nested children in an app. The highest level component manages all the state everything else is stateless. Now in the component I've provided code for above I want to carry out a database operation with values that are currently in `props.group` and then remove the row from a list. Currently the onDeleteTracker is defined at the top level component and passed down the chain to the above component. I'm now considering how do I get the values of this component back to the top level component to tell it which items to delete. Should I just be performing the delete functionality within the TrackerRow component instead of passing the prop values back to the toplevel component as function parameters. Is there any reasoning which method to use here? I'm unclear of the pros and cons of either method (or alternatives.)

Comment: I think the way you have it is preferable. Just pass whatever arguments you need to `onDeleteTracker`

Answer (score 0):

Definitely pass the instruction to 'delete item x' up to the component that manages state (or straight through to a store if you had one).

Actually I don't think there's even a choice. Remember that you can't mutate props, and that the data source is represented as state in the parent component.

But are you removing a 'group'? Or are you removing a 'campaign'? From your code, the property `group` appears to just be an array of `campaign`s (for what it's worth, I'd suggest always using the plural of the item for arrays, e.g. renaming 'group' to 'campaigns').

So I'll guess that you're actually wanting to remove a campaign, in which case you would call `onDeleteTracker` from inside the `<CampaignRow/>` component (when it's clicked or whatever). Which would look something like `onClick={() => props.onDeleteTracker(props.id)}`.